# Math expression solver

Tags: java, beginner, parsing, recursion, math-expression-eval

I've recently stumbled upon an interesting challenge for me:

> You should develop C application, that solves math expressions. Operations such as (+,-,*,/) should be supported, as well as (cos, sin, exp). Application should replace constants Pi and E with built-in values. We may have any amount of spaces between operators and braces.
>
> Example:
>
> stdin: 11 + (exp(2.010635 + sin(PI/2)*3) + 50) / 2
>
> stdout: 111.00000 (may have insignificant deviations)

I am interested in solving this problem using Java. I know that the best way is to use lexical analysis or regexp, but for now it is too complex for me. I am trying to solve this task without them. My code works well, but it looks awful, I think.

My code is also on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ijSyh4CK).

Can you help me make my code style better?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
 
/**
 * Created by Vladimir on 20.02.14.
 */
public class Main {
    private static final ArrayList<Character> DIVIDERS = new ArrayList<Character>
            (Arrays.asList('*', '/', '-', '+'));
    private static final int RIGHT_DIRECTION = 1;
    private static final int LEFT_DIRECTION = -1;
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String expression = "";
 
        System.out.print("Enter expression: ");
        try {
            expression = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Expression: " + expression);
 
        expression = prepareExpression(expression);
 
        System.out.println("Prepared expression: " + expression);
 
        System.out.println("Answer: " + calc(expression));
 
    }
 
    //Recursive function with the state machine
    //states "(", "sin", "cos", "exp", "*", "/", "+", "-"
    private static String calc(String expression) {
        int pos = 0;
        System.out.println("Solving expression: "+expression);
        //Extracting expression from braces, doing recursive call
        //replace braced expression on result of it solving
        if (-1 != (pos = expression.indexOf("("))) {
 
            String subexp = extractExpressionFromBraces(expression,pos);
            expression = expression.replace("("+subexp+")", calc(subexp));
 
            return calc(expression);
 
        //Three states for calculating sin cos exp
        //input must be like sin0.7
        } else if (-1 != (pos = expression.indexOf("sin"))) {
 
            pos += 2;//shift index to last symbol of "sin" instead of first
 
            String number = extractNumber(expression, pos, RIGHT_DIRECTION);
 
            expression = expression.replace("sin"+number, 
                    Double.toString(Math.sin(Double.parseDouble(number))));
 
            return calc(expression);
 
        } else if (-1 != (pos = expression.indexOf("cos"))) {
 
            pos += 2;
 
            String number = extractNumber(expression, pos, RIGHT_DIRECTION);
 
            expression = expression.replace("cos"+number, 
                    Double.toString(Math.cos(Double.parseDouble(number))));
 
            return calc(expression);
 
        } else if (-1 != (pos = expression.indexOf("exp"))) {
 
            pos += 2;
 
            String number = extractNumber(expression, pos, RIGHT_DIRECTION);
 
            expression = expression.replace("exp" + number, 
                    Double.toString(Math.exp(Double.parseDouble(number))));
 
            return calc(expression);
 
       
        } else if (expression.indexOf("*") > 0 | expression.indexOf("/") > 0) {
 
            int multPos = expression.indexOf("*");
            int divPos = expression.indexOf("/");
 
            pos = Math.min(multPos, divPos);
            if (multPos < 0) pos = divPos; else if (divPos < 0) pos = multPos; 
                //If one value of
                //*Pos will be -1 result of min will be incorrect.
 
            char divider = expression.charAt(pos);
 
            String leftNum = extractNumber(expression, pos, LEFT_DIRECTION);
            String rightNum = extractNumber(expression, pos, RIGHT_DIRECTION);
 
            expression = expression.replace(leftNum + divider + rightNum, 
                calcShortExpr(leftNum, rightNum, divider));
 
            return calc(expression);
 
        
        } else if (expression.indexOf("+") > 0 | expression.indexOf("-") > 0) {
 
            int summPos = expression.indexOf("+");
            int minusPos = expression.indexOf("-");
 
            pos = Math.min(summPos, minusPos);
 
            if (summPos < 0) pos = minusPos; else if (minusPos < 0) pos = summPos;
 
            char divider = expression.charAt(pos);
 
            String leftNum = extractNumber(expression, pos, LEFT_DIRECTION);
            String rightNum = extractNumber(expression, pos, RIGHT_DIRECTION);
 
            expression = expression.replace(leftNum + divider + rightNum, 
                calcShortExpr(leftNum, rightNum, divider));
 
            return calc(expression);
 
        } else return expression;
    }
 
    private static String extractExpressionFromBraces(String expression, int pos) {
        int braceDepth = 1;
        String subexp="";
 
        for (int i = pos+1; i < expression.length(); i++) {
            switch (expression.charAt(i)) {
                case '(':
                    braceDepth++;
                    subexp += "(";
                    break;
                case ')':
                    braceDepth--;
                    if (braceDepth != 0) subexp += ")";
                    break;
                default:
                    if (braceDepth > 0) subexp += expression.charAt(i);
 
            }
            if (braceDepth == 0 && !subexp.equals("")) return subexp;
        }
        return "Failure!";
    }
 
    private static String extractNumber(String expression, int pos, int direction) {
 
        String resultNumber = "";
        int currPos = pos + direction;//shift pos on next symbol from divider
 
        //For negative numbers
        if (expression.charAt(currPos) == '-') {
            resultNumber+=expression.charAt(currPos);
            currPos+=direction;
        }
 
        for (; currPos >= 0 &&
               currPos < expression.length() &&
               !DIVIDERS.contains(expression.charAt(currPos));
               currPos += direction) {
            resultNumber += expression.charAt(currPos);
        }
 
        if (direction==LEFT_DIRECTION) resultNumber = new 
                StringBuilder(resultNumber).reverse().toString();
 
        return resultNumber;
    }
 
    private static String calcShortExpr(String leftNum, String rightNum, char divider) {
        switch (divider) {
            case '*':
                return Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(leftNum) * 
                        Double.parseDouble(rightNum));
            case '/':
                return Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(leftNum) / 
                        Double.parseDouble(rightNum));
            case '+':
                return Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(leftNum) + 
                        Double.parseDouble(rightNum));
            case '-':
                return Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(leftNum) - 
                        Double.parseDouble(rightNum));
            default:
                return "0";
        }
 
    }
   
    private static String prepareExpression(String expression) {
 
        expression = expression.replace("PI", Double.toString(Math.PI));
        expression = expression.replace("E", Double.toString(Math.E));
        expression = expression.replace(" ", "");
 
        return expression;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with that a different approach would be better, so just a few random notes, mostly about the current code:

1. It's good to know that it's already in the JDK, in form a script engine. So, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel just use it:

   ```
   import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
   import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

   final ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
   final ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
   String expression = "11 + (Math.exp(2.010635 + Math.sin(Math.PI/2)*3) + 50) / 2";
   System.out.println(engine.eval(expression)); // prints 110.99997794278411
   ```

   The syntax is not the same (you need the `Math.` prefix) but I guess it can be changed.
2. Instead of doubles (and floating point numbers) consider using `BigDecimal`s. Floating point numbers are not precise. Here is an example:

   ```
   Enter expression: 1.03-0.42
   Expression: 1.03-0.42
   Prepared expression: 1.03-0.42
   Solving expression: 1.03-0.42
   Solving expression: 0.6100000000000001
   Answer: 0.6100000000000001
   ```

   (It might not fit well for trigonometric functions.)

   - [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/843804)
   - *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 48: Avoid float and double if exact answers are required*
3. `DIVIDERS` currently mutable. You could wrap it with `Collections.unmodifiableList` to avoid accidental modification. A more compact form is [Guava's `ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html):

   ```
   private static final List<Character> DIVIDERS = ImmutableList.of('*', '/', '-', '+');
   ```
4. In some places I would use a`String.contains` instead of `indexOf`. It's more meaningful, closer to the English language, easier to read since you cat get rid of the comparison. In conditionals like this

   ```
   expression.indexOf("*") > 0 | expression.indexOf("/") > 0
   ```

   I'd use the even more compact

   ```
   StringUtils.containsAny(expression, "*/")
   ```

   ([from Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsAny%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29))
5. The following lines also could be replaced with `StringUtils`:

   ```
   int multPos = expression.indexOf("*");
   int divPos = expression.indexOf("/");

   pos = Math.min(multPos, divPos);
   if (multPos < 0)
       pos = divPos;
   else if (divPos < 0)
       pos = multPos;
   ```

   Use [`indexOfAny`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#indexOfAny%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence...%29):

   ```
   pos = StringUtils.indexOfAny(expression, "*/")
   ```

   It's the same.
6. Instead of returning with an error string, like

   ```
   return "Failure!";
   ```

   I think you should throw an exception and stop the processing immediately, there is no point to "continue" the processing with wrong subresult (or to pretend that it continues). (*The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt* and *David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*.)

   The same is true for the default branch of `calcShortExpr`. If you call it with an invalid "divider" it's definitely an error in the program and it should stop.
7. The `divider` variable actually contains the operator which is a little bit confusing. I'd rename it for better readability.

Answer (score 6):

You're right that a proper expression parser would be the superior approach.  Nevertheless, your *ad hoc* solution works surprisingly well, though it will have some odd behaviour.

I'll just start by pointing out that your exception handling in `main()` is shaky.  If you get an `IOException`, you'll print a stack trace, then proceed to evaluate an empty string anyway.

What you probably want to do if there is an `IOException` is to skip the rest of the program:

```
try {
    String expression = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("Expression: " + expression);
    expression = prepareExpression(expression);
    System.out.println("Prepared expression: " + expression);
    System.out.println("Answer: " + calc(expression));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this particular case, since all you do is print a stack trace and abort, you could just take advantage of Java's default behaviour.  All you have to do is declare that `main()` can throw an `IOException`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Enter expression: ");
    String expression = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("Expression: " + expression);

    expression = prepareExpression(expression);
    System.out.println("Prepared expression: " + expression);

    System.out.println("Answer: " + calc(expression));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I understand that this project has been posted many years ago but I have noticed a mistake: the program works perfectly except when the first number is negative.

For example, with the following input: `-8 + 3`. The program enters the function (see stacktrace below) and fails to execute the calculation.

> ```
> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
>     at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
>     at Main.extractNumber(Main.java:161)
> ```